# Monotouch Paging ViewControllers keeps adding views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin, paging

I am creating an app that is required to be able to swipe between views. I used the sample code from [here](http://escoz.com/blog/paging-controllers-with-monotouch/) to get started. The issue I am having is that when I go from one `ViewController` to the paged `ViewControllers` then back again the `ViewControllers` are added to the list and the list keeps growing. I get duplicate `ViewControllers` on the screen that I can scroll through. The new list is just added to the end of the already populated `viewControllers`.

I am not using a navigation controller on the home screen it is simply a scroll view with buttons on it. This is part of the HomeViewController class:

```
private void BuildScrollView()
    {
        float padding = 0.0f;
        float h = 80.0f;

        UIView content = new UIView (new RectangleF (15, 130, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 30, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height));
        content.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(ColorManager.Grey_undrline_RGB[0], ColorManager.Grey_undrline_RGB[1], ColorManager.Grey_undrline_RGB[2]);


        UIScrollView scrollView = new UIScrollView {
            Frame = new RectangleF(2, 2, content.Frame.Width - 4 , content.Frame.Height -4), 
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(ColorManager.Grey_backgrd_RGB[0], ColorManager.Grey_backgrd_RGB[1], ColorManager.Grey_backgrd_RGB[2]),
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        };
        List<myObject> prayerList = myObjectBuilder.GeObjectFiles ();

        for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++){

            UIView btnView = new UIView(new RectangleF (padding  , padding * (i + 1) + (i * h), scrollView.Frame.Width - (padding * 2), h));
            btnView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB (ColorManager.Grey_backgrd_RGB [0], ColorManager.Grey_backgrd_RGB [1], ColorManager.Grey_backgrd_RGB [2]);

            myButton btnImage = new myButton (new RectangleF (3, 3, 135, 80));


            UIImage tempImage = new UIImage ("Images/bottomImages/" + myList[i].bottomImage ).Scale(new SizeF(135, 80));

            btnImage.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (tempImage);
            btnImage.PrayerID = i;
            btnImage.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                LoadPrayerView(sender);
            };

            btnView.AddSubview (btnImage);

            myButton button = new myButton(new RectangleF (141, 3, btnView.Frame.Width - 145, h));
            button.PrayerID = i;

            button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            button.SetTitle (myList[i].ShortTitle.ToUpper(), UIControlState.Normal);
            button.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
            button.HorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left;

            button.TitleLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName ("HelveticaNeue", 16.0f);
            button.TitleLabel.Lines = 0;
            button.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            button.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets (0, 10, 0, 10);

            button.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                LoadView(sender);
            };

            btnView.AddSubview (button);
            scrollView.AddSubview (btnView);

        }

        scrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF (scrollView.Frame.Width, (prayerList.Count + 2) * (h + padding) + padding);

        content.AddSubview (scrollView);
        this.View.AddSubview (content);

    }
```

I can post more code if needed. At this point I am not really sure where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: Where is BuildScrollView being called from?  It sounds like it is being initialized multiple times.

Comment: It is getting called from the ViewDidLoad method on my HomeViewcontroller.

Comment: You need to add more code. There is to much missing to figure out what is going on.